# infinity vectors in Spark MLlib word2vec

Tags: apache-spark, word2vec

I have a question about running word2vec of Spark MLlib.
 I run it with vocabulary size ~2.4M and corpus size ~1.4B. 
 What is the reason to get +-infinity vectors for some words?
It happens when I increase the number of iterations, namely, with 10 iteration I get a reasonable model, 
and with 20 iteration I get some vectors of the form [Infinity,-Infinity,Infinity,-Infinity,...]. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -2):

you can do like this for each vector elements:

```
  def input_data(data_input:Double):Double =  {
  var result = data_input
  if (data_input.isInfinity || data_input.isNaN){
    result =0
  }
  result
}
```

Comment: This answer fixes the symptom but does not solve the problem. The word2vec model should not contain Infinities in the first place.